# Htaccess - Multiple Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file and I want to add more parameters to the resources page like I have now.

Now I have: `/resources/<id>`

But I want: `/resources/<id>/<name>`

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+resources(?:\.php)?\?id=([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ resources/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^resources/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/?$ resources.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile(?:\.php)?\?id=([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+error(?:\.php)?\?id=([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ error/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^error/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/?$ error.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 400 /error/400
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503

Redirect /index.php /home
Redirect /index.html /home
RewriteRule /sitemap.xml /sitemap.xml.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bellow this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/?$ resources.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/?$ resources.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```